# Altium Polygon Pour Order Issues

Tags: altium, copper-pour

I am using Altium Designer 14.1 and I do not know if it is an issue with this version or something else.

The problem I am having is I have a solid copper pour covering the whole board. I want to put a smaller polygon pour somewhere in the in the middle of it. No matter what pour order I put the smaller polygon pour in, when it is totally inside the bigger polygon pour, it looks like the program is defaulting the smaller polygon to an outline only. However, when I put the smaller polygon on the side of the larger one (hanging half on and half off), it will cutout accordingly: the smaller one will be whole if it is first (above in the pour order) and cutout the larger one; or if the pour order is the larger above the smaller, the smaller polygon will be cut out.

I hope someone can help me solve this. I do not know why it will not pour correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the polygon settings, do you have "remove dead copper" checked? Are you sure it's set to the right net name? Are you using rooms? Also is there a design rule which may affect this net?

Comment: This often happens when there's only a single connection to the pour. Have you checked that the inner pour connects to multiple components? Also check to make sure its type (in the polygon pour properties) is not set to "Outline".

Comment: You may consider assigning polygon pours a different net name, then link them together. Routers cannot tell how different sections with the same net name can share the same space. This is why star typologies for analog are often manually routed.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate and thank all that provided the above comments to my issue and perhaps some of the suggested solutions may work with something similar but I determined the cause of my problem.

I discovered that it actually dealt with the actual pouring of the copper. Once the original larger copper polygon was poured, trying to overlay a smaller copper polygon with copper already present, it just did not pour as there was not any empty space for the new smaller polygon to pour. When I shelved the larger polygon, poured the smaller polygon, and then subsequently repoured the larger polygon, both polygons behaved as they should have. I was too used to EAGLE auto repouring all polygons.

I accidentally discovered this because for whatever reason, I chose to shelve the larger polygon so I could line up the smaller one where I needed it to be and then unshelved the larger one and it poured around the smaller one. I think the pour order will be only important if you chose to shelve multiple polygon pours and then just restore them all with the single click of restore all or repour all.

Comment: You do not need to shelve the polygons in order to get them to respect the ordering defined in the polygon manager. Simply re-pour all of them. Repouring individual polygons will repour them in place which doesn't follow the precedence, but using the repour all command does